# Issue with getting a LineString with repeated lat/lngs from SQL Server using the npm mssql library it buffer throws index out range error

Tags: node.js, sql-server, npm

When I try to get a Linestring with repeated lat/lngs in node js from SQL server using the npm mssql. It throws an error, the buffer is some how corrupted and it give wrong information about the data in it. Due to which it leads to index out of range error.

> Index out of range
>       at checkOffset (buffer.js:977:11)
>       at Buffer.readUInt32LE (buffer.js:1039:5)
>       at parseGeography (E:\WorkSpace\App\node_modules\mssql\lib\udt.js:277:39)

The linestring on which it generated the error. It have same lat/lng on index 2 and index 4.

```
LINESTRING (73.0409597 33.6832051, 73.0409599 33.6832046, 73.0409598 33.6832048, 73.0409599 33.6832046)
```